# Bootstrap Modal Not scrolling after close then open

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function the when clicked closes the active modal, then right away opens the one that was clicked on based on the modal IDs.

```
$("#"+currentModal).modal('hide');

$("#"+name).modal({keyboard:false,backdrop:'static'});
$("#"+name).modal('show');
```

But when the second modal is opened it does not scroll. The modal is bigger than the window and the scroll bar scrolls the page grayed out behind the modal.

But the first modal is also bigger than the window but the scroll bar acts as it should. Is there something wrong with closing and then opening a modal right away? The right modals are being opened and closed so the problem is not the IDs being passed but the only issue is the scroll bar not being with the modal.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of what issues you are having?

Answer (score 1):

If both the modals show fine individually, it could be due to a conflict with operations. Try to show the second modal on event `hidden.bs.modal` of first modal.

```
$("#"+currentModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $("#"+name).modal({keyboard:false,backdrop:'static'});
          $("#"+name).modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: this would mean that every time the `currentModal` is closed (whether its from the specified function or just a close button on that modal), the second modal will show up. just and fyi since it wasnt clear whether OP wanted the second modal to trigger every time the first modal closed.

Comment: @indubitable you are right, I don't need the second to fire every time the first is closed. The second only fires when it is clicked on. That fires the function which does the above code. "close active, then open new" But you can also just close the active modal. So this wouldn't work necessarily.

Comment: @workingxx, you can try if this works and if it works fine, set a variable to check if the second modal needs to be open and then close the first modal. This can effectively show the second modal if needed.